# Images does not scroll in ViewPager in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing View-pager in List-view as row item .When run the application my images is not scrolling one by one in view pager. What is the wrong in my code. Can someone suggest me how to make it work or scrolling smoothly images in view pager.

Here is my code

```
public class Demo_Display extends Activity {

    private String str[] = {"weklfjo","??2","??3"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this,R.layout.row,str);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        private static final float BUTTON_WIDTH_DP = 70f;
        private int margin;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource,String[] items) {
            super(context, resource,items);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int buttonWidthPX = (int) (BUTTON_WIDTH_DP * density + 0.5f);

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(getContext().WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display dp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            margin = dp.getWidth() - buttonWidthPX;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
            }

            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Image_ViewPagers);
            viewPager.setPageMargin(-margin);
            // MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext(),getItem(position));

            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            return convertView;
        }
    }


    class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context mContent;
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

        private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.flower1,
                R.drawable.flower1
        };



        public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            super();
            mContent = context;
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContent.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContent);
            int padding = mContent.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_button_padding_horizontal_material);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;


        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            // return PAGE_NUM;
            return GalImages.length;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {

            //return view.equals(obj);
            return view == ((ImageView) obj);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_InitialLetter"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:text="jsdygf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Desc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:text="sdkjhfeorygdshgvfsjd" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp" >


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/Image_ViewPagers"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/reply_blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/retweet_blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/star" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/recorder_blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/follow_up" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

and List View xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added a scrollView in the xml?

Comment: I have solve the problem own. Thanks for the reply .